# Open an URL in a new tab

Tags: angular

I know there is a `$window service` in Angular 1.x. Now, I want to open an URL in a new tab, I haven't found any service to do this.

**UPDATE:**
Seems Angular 2 itself doesn't provide a method/service like Angular 1.x. If you want to navigate inside of an Angular app, you can refer to [Angular Router - navigate()](http://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate). I'm asking this question because I want to navigate using some method provided by Angular, but none of the answers is what I expect.

Comment: this is now possible in angular router check this [fix](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/fa2ce8100b02e00d2e48c653f91f587f5e6ec540)

Comment: @MurhafSousli thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like the OP wanted to know how to use $window in angular2 to open a link in either a new tab or window - not to distinguish between them. In case this helps anyone, first declare window:

```
interface MyWindow extends Window {
    myFunction(): void;
}

declare var window: MyWindow;
```

then open the link as usual

```
window.open(url);
```

Comment: Hi @Dovev Hefetz... your answer is like gem for me..thanks

Comment: can we open that url in new window instead of new tab?

Comment: @Ricky New window vs new tab is a browser preference that can't be controlled by code afaik

Answer (score 7):

You can set target="_blank" on your anchor tag to open the URL in a new tab.

```
<a [href]="url" target="_blank">Some URL</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `nagivationEnd` event and in HTML page of your componet use this `[routerLink]="moduleMenu.ROUTE"`

```js
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            let subMenu: Menus = new Menus();
            var appName: string = localStorage.getItem('activeGroupModuleName');
            var menuItems: Menus[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('MenuList')) as Menus[];

            if (event.url != '/atpar') {
                if (menuItems != null && menuItems != undefined) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
                        if (event.url.indexOf(menuItems[i].ROUTE) >= 0 && appName == menuItems[i].APP_NAME) {
                            subMenu = menuItems[i];
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    localStorage.setItem('submenu', JSON.stringify(subMenu));
                    this.title.setTitle(AtParConstants.PRODUCT_NAME + ' - ' + subMenu.MENU_NAME);
                }
                else {
                    this.title.setTitle(AtParConstants.PRODUCT_NAME + ' - ' + 'Dashboard');
                }
            }
            else {
                this.title.setTitle(AtParConstants.PRODUCT_NAME + ' - Dashboard');
            }
        }
    });
```